# Why I am getting weird a phase change in the following

Tags: mosfet, amplifier, voltage-divider

[image]

This is voltage divider bias for MOSFET simulated on multisim. Some connection are not visible due to probe connection.
When i remove the bypass capacitor at emitter, i get normal phase difference of 180

Comment: In your MultiSim schematic, the values for resistors R4 and R5 are 40 milliohms (40M) and 10 milliohms (10M) respectively. If you intended them to be 40 megohms and 10 megohms, you must use 'MEG' as the multiplier suffix--i.e., 40MEG and 10MEG. (n.b. In SPICE, 'm' and 'M' have the same meaning, 'milli'.)

Answer (score -1):

- let C3R2 = C2R3 = T = 100ms for 1kHz for max output and 180 phase shift
- for both T= 10ms phase shift starts to be worse and gain reduced.
- verify RC values.